# Audio delay in unity (windows)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an issue when using audio files in unity (to windows platform) with the AudioSource + AudioClip classes, when telling the AudioSource to start play the sound it takes a lot of time until it actually starts (sometimes more then a second or 2 after I see the printed log).

```
audioSource.clip = audioClip;
audioSource.Play();
Debug.Log("audiosource play");
```

the files are .wav (48000Hz  1536 kb/s IEEE FLOAT), I tried other types of files (.wav 48000Hz  768 kb/s PCM Audio, and also mp3) and the problem is still there.

I tried to change the settings of the audioClip (Load Type, Preload Audio Data, compression format and sample rate setting) and it did not help either.
finally I tried to change the settings in the Project Settings -> Audio -> all the settings there and still the same problem.

the audio files sizes are not big (about 700 KB) and I am using Unity 2018.3.4f1

Comment: this sounds strange, do you have a minimal working environment where this behaviour occures?

Comment: Yes I am using a strong computer with windows 10 on it (also tried another laptop and it was the same)

Comment: please post your minimal working environment, where this behaviour occures.

Comment: Are you making it stream those assets? so perhaps it has to download them before it can play them

Comment: BugFinder thanks it was because of what you said. now it works